# android SensorEventListener doesn't write what it should

Tags: java, android

So I'm starting to work with Android's sensor management and such, and I want to make a simple application that allows the user to choose a specific kind of sensor, and then shows the information for that sensor (both some specifications and the current data). Currently it should show the acceleration, gravity changes, linear acceleration or rotation vector sensor depending on the choice, but for some reason the TextView only shows what it should when the user chooses acceleration, it only shows the default text for the other 3.

Here's my current code for this view:

```
package com.example.helloandroidworld;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Actividad que muestra los datos del sensor seleccionado. Recibe la informacion
 * del metodo que la llama en la actividad principal.
 *
 * @author Guillermo Diaz
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 18-01-2018
 */
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);

    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    String st = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_INFO);
    SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            TextView textView4 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            String ret = "";
            if (event.sensor.getType() == 1) {
                ret += event.values[0] + "\n";
                ret += event.values[1] + "\n";
                ret += event.values[2] + "\n";
                textView4.setText(ret);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor s, int i) {
        }
    };
    switch (st) {
        case "Acelerometro":
            sm.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                    10000);
            break;
        case "Gravitometro":
            sm.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY),
                    10000);
            break;
        case "Acelerometro lineal":
            sm.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION),
                    10000);
            break;
        case "Sensor de vector de rotacion":
            sm.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR),
                    10000);
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And in case it was necessary, this is the associated xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/default_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/sensor_select"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the method that triggers this activity:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void checkData(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        Sensor select = properSensor((String)spinner2.getSelectedItem());
        String message = sensorData(select);

        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INFO, sensorType.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

As stated earlier, the accelerator choice actually works as intended, but the other 3 just refuse to. Any help would be appreciated, and if any more context (such as the code for the entire previous activity) is required, by all means tell me so

Comment: You're only setting the text if the sensor type is `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` – `if (event.sensor.getType() == 1)`.

Comment: oh crap, you're right. I must be blind or something. Thanks a lot!